# Number of emojis in a String?

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring, emoji

With recently added iOS 9.1 emojis, and the availability of skin tones etc, how do you properly count the number of Emojis in a String, assuming the string is uniquely made out of emojis?

Keep in mind that the length of emojis can vary.

NSString.length or string.characters.count

"" returns 2
"✊" returns 4
"" or "" or "" returns 1!
"‍‍‍" returns 4 (Should be normally displayed as 1 family emoji)
etc...

Comment: Just use the string length method - it returns the number of characters in a string, not the number of bytes, so multi-byte characters, such as Emoji, are catered for

Comment: @Paulw11 string length is returning 2 for regular emojis and 4 for emojis with skin tone. What's even weirder it's that it's returning 1 for a string of n flags.

Comment: Hmm. The flag issue is described here - http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/ Basically it seems that the combination of grapheme clusters isn't quite "right" yet, perhaps because the Unicode spec for some of this is still draft.  For example, "‍‍‍" in a string decomposes to  ‍ ‍ ‍  if you access the `characters` property of the string

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 5):

I make an extension of `String` to count number of emoji in a string:

```
extension String {
    func countEmojiCharacter() -> Int {

        func isEmoji(s:NSString) -> Bool {

            let high:Int = Int(s.characterAtIndex(0))
            if 0xD800 <= high && high <= 0xDBFF {
                let low:Int = Int(s.characterAtIndex(1))
                let codepoint: Int = ((high - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000
                return (0x1D000 <= codepoint && codepoint <= 0x1F9FF)
            }
            else {
                return (0x2100 <= high && high <= 0x27BF)
            }
        }

        let nsString = self as NSString
        var length = 0

        nsString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length), options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByComposedCharacterSequences) { (subString, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> Void in

            if isEmoji(subString!) {
                length++
            }
        }

        return length
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let y = "xxxzzz"

print(y.countEmojiCharacter())
// result is 3
```

Comment: You could use this library to help deal with parsing emojis in strings. http://github.com/jkalash/jkemoji

Answer (score 2):

try this code snippet

```
extension String {
    var composedCount : Int {
        var count = 0
        enumerateSubstringsInRange(startIndex..<endIndex, options: .ByComposedCharacterSequences) {_ in count++}
        return count
    }
}
```

: credit goes to [ericasadun](http://ericasadun.com/2015/04/16/swift-counting-emoji-groups/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code [example](http://github.com/GabrielMassana/SearchEmojiOnString) or this [pod](http://cocoapods.org/pods/SearchEmojiOnString).

To use it in Swift, import the category into the `YourProject_Bridging_Header`

```
#import "NSString+EMOEmoji.h"
```

Then you can check the range for every emoji in your String:

```
let example: NSString = "string‍‍‍withemojis✊" //string with emojis

let emojiCount: NSInteger = example.emo_emojiCount()  // count

print(emojiCount)

// Output: ["3"]
```

[I created an small example project with the code above.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/GetEmoji)

**UPDATE**

Running this code with >= iOS 8.3 will have an

```
// Output: ["3"]
```

Running this code with < iOS 8.3 will have an

```
// Output: ["7"]
```

This is because family emoji, skin tone and many others were introduced with iOS 8.3. So, a smaller iOS version are reading this emojis in a different way.

As a example, open this post in Safari, Firefox and Chrome to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (actual for Swift 5):

```
extension Character {
    var isSimpleEmoji: Bool {
        guard let firstScalar = unicodeScalars.first else { return false }
        return firstScalar.properties.isEmoji && firstScalar.value > 0x238C
    }

    var isEmoji: Bool {
        return isSimpleEmoji
    }
}

extension String {
    var emojis: [Character] { filter { $0.isEmoji } }
}
```

Use:

```
let emojisCount = yourString.emojis.count
```

Answer (score 1):

some situation(e.g. netty):

```
"‍‍‍".utf8.count
```

Answer (score 0):

swift4 answer:

```
extension String {
    var composedCount : Int {
        var count = 0
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byComposedCharacterSequences) { (_, _, _, _) in
            count = count + 1
        }

        return count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Emojis, much like the unicode standard, are deceptively complicated. Skin tones, genders, jobs, groups of people, zero-width joiner sequences, flags (2 character unicode) and other complications can make emoji parsing messy. A Christmas Tree, a Slice of Pizza, or a Pile of Poop can all be represented with a single Unicode code point. Not to mention that when new emojis are introduced, there is a delay between iOS support and emoji release. That and the fact that different versions of iOS support different versions of the unicode standard.

**TL;DR.** I have worked on these features and opened sourced a library I am the author for [JKEmoji](http://github.com/jkalash/jkemoji) to help parse strings with emojis. It makes parsing as easy as:

```
print("I love these emojis ‍‍‍".emojiCount)
```

> 5

It does that by routinely refreshing a local database of all recognized emojis as of the latest unicode version ([12.0](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/) as of recently) and cross-referencing them with what is recognized as a valid emoji in the running OS version by looking at the bitmap representation of an unrecognized emoji character.

**NOTE**

A previous answer got deleted for advertising my library without clearly stating that I am the author. I am acknowledging this again.